How do I add an image to a desktop item?
Today I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. On Ubuntu 22.04 I could assign an image to a file on my desktop. How do I add an image to a desktop item? I could do this on Ubuntu 22.04. For example, for my file named Accounts.ods I added the below image.


If you tell about desktop icons you can try open it in Kate (or other text editor) and add this:
Icon=/path_to_your_image
Example from my desktop icon:
icon

Thanks but sorry I do not understand and your solution seems too complicated for Ubuntu 24 compared with the ease of assigning an image to a file or directory  in Ubuntu 22.

You want to add an image to a file specifically via GUI? Then you need to tell what GUI you're using (GNOME, KDE, Cinnamon, etc) and its version.

Ubuntu 24-04 GNOME.

On Ubuntu 24.04 I can add an image to a folder on my desktop but not to a file. Problem bypassed but not really satisfactory.
